# htaccess to force https "www" to redirect to non "www"

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I know there are a few topics on this, but all of the configurations that I've tried usually make my site not accessible at all. My issue is that we recently got an SSL certificate but only for the non "www" version of the site, but if a user would write the URL with "www" they would get an insecure site message. This is the current htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

For example this configuration won't do anything either:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Don't forget that dns & redirects are often cached by your browser / system so some redirects wont actually take affect for several hours despite clearing browser cache. I'd avoid make frequent changes and trying different redirects. Try something then leave it for a day and then test it. If it doesnt work try the next one and leave for a day. Also, turn off all network level and site level caching until you have this fixed. Remember to use Velvet URLs or a similar plugin to rewrite all your site links to non 'www' and change the site url in WP Admin before doing anything else.

Comment: I'll see if it works after a while thank you.

Comment: You could be looking at a whole day or so.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on apache (as I think), tou could try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Of course be sure to not have "www." in your site settings, because this can break the whole site.

You could also redirect www to non-www in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Also, this can help to avoid mixed content warning. Always put it in .htaccess

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
```

Cheers

Comment: I've tried all sorts of redirects to no avail. If I try it on Firefox, and the user writes the URL with "www" they don't get redirected at all and get the site not secure message. That simple one won't work.

Comment: In that case I would contact hosting provider and ask if "mod rewrite" is enabled. If server is not following .htaccess rules is quite strange

Comment: I see this firefox-only problem here with a wordpress installation too. Somehow the rewrite in firefox does not omit the www. and goes to https://www.dns.com instead of https://dns.com - is there a known bug with firefox?